# How to access value from other file by file read operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

There are two files.

1. Master file(file name => transaction.js)
2. Object decelaration file(file name => checkin.txt)

**2**. **Object decelaration file(checkin.txt)**

```
    {cronCondition: true,startDate:""}
```

**1.** **Master File(file name => transaction.js)**

```
fs.readFile((__dirname + "/ checkin.txt"), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
     if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         process.exit(0);
     }else{
        console.log(data);
        process.exit();
     }
 })
```

When I console.log the value of data, it returns **{cronCondition: true,startDate:""}**. It is fine to me but I want to access only the value of **cronCondition**. For this, I tried console **data.cronCondition**. It returns **undefined**.

How do you access the value of **cronCondition** ?

Comment: You might need to `eval()` the string content of the file to convert it to object

Comment: You get back a string since `fs.readFile( [...] 'utf8' [...])`. You should use `let parsedData = JSON.parse(data); console.log(parsedData.cronCondition);`

Comment: Make your file in json format -> cronDate.txt to cronDate.json
if you don't want to change then convert the data in object format.
do like this. JSON.parse(data); then access it.

Comment: @Bellian I tried `JSON.parse(data)` it reurns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1`

Comment: You are right, since this is not valid JSON :/ Sorry for that. in JSON the names have to be escaped in `"`: `{"cronCondition": true,"startDate":""}`.

Comment: @Shadow I changed cronData.txt file in json format but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Your source file `cronDate.txt` contains JSON that is technically invalid, so you will you need to use a library that parses JSON with "relaxed" rules (e.g., JSON without quotes, JSON with single quotes, line breaks, etc) . [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) is a library that can do just that.

**Install:**

```
npm install json5
const JSON5 = require('json5')
```

**Usage:**

```
fs.readFile((__dirname + "/cronDate.txt"), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
     console.log(err);
     process.exit(0);
  } else {
    var test = JSON5.parse(data);
    console.log(test);
    process.exit();
  }
})
```

Also, I noticed a slight contradiction in your question. The top of your question states that your source file is `checkin.txt` while the file you're actually reading from is `cronDate.txt`. You'll want to verify that you are reading from the correct file. **Edit:** It looks like you've now corrected your original question.

Answer (score 0):

First change format of second file in json format

**2.Object decelaration file(checkin.json)**

```
{"cronCondition":false,"startDate":"2018-02-07T18:30:00.000Z"}
```

**1.Master file(file name => transaction.js)**

> var cronValue = require('./checkin.json');

```
console.log("cronData==>", cronValue.cronCondition)
```

I think no need to read file operation.